# react.js - Server-side rendering and routes strategies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, render, reactjs

I'm currently starting my first React app with server-side rendering. The problem is that I want to choose the most solid strategy.

What I'm currently trying to do:

- using Swig as template engine for Express app and inserting stringified React component like template variable:

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="react-mount">{{reactHTML|safe}}</div>
       <script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- here is the problem of passing props into components on both server-side and client-side:

**server**

```
var Box = require('./src/components/Box.jsx');
function renderify (component, props) {
   var reactHTML = React.renderToString(React.createElement(component, props));
   return {reactHTML: reactHTML};
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('layout', renderify(Box, {name: 'My Box'}));
});
```

This renders on server perfectly, but client doesn't know that I have `name` prop..

**client**

```
var React = require('react');
var Box = require('./components/Box.jsx');

React.render(<Box />, document.getElementById('react-mount'));
```

Which throws me a warning from React and rerenders the page without `name`.

---

Another question here is routing..  I assume that it's better to render app on server when some route is requested but then I will prefer to have client-side location change when user goes through application..

Does this mean that routes should be duplicated on both client and server?

---

#### So what is the best strategy from your experience to render React components on the server?

Answer (score 1):

To correctly "upgrade" a server-rendered component into a client-managed component (e.g. without the warning), you need to mount the same component on the client as you rendered on the server, and pass it the same props. If the props can be dynamic, then you'll also need to get the props from the server to the client, e.g. by serializing them to JSON and then reading them out on the client before the component mounts.

A good React routing solution ([react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) is a great choice) will allow you to declaratively set up your routes based on the URL and query parameters, which frees you from having to manage and serialize that data yourself. [Here's a quick example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/server-rendering.md) from the react-router docs.

Comment: Do I need duplicate routes in client-side `bundle.js` and server code?

Comment: @Kosmetika Projects like react-router allow you to define your routes using React components; on the server, you could use a catch-all route that just renders the component to a string, like in the example I linked (`app.use` makes the React router run for every request).

Comment: Yeah, thanks! There's another problem though.. As my components speak with JSON API in order to have data in their `state`'s server rendering won't give me benefit until I'll figure out what is the best way to fetch this data on server and to avoid duplicate functionality..